# Angular: route.params returns "null" instead of null

Tags: angular, routes, null

I can not return a null value in my route.params. Instead it returns a string containing a `string: "null"`

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params=> {
    console.log(typeof params['parameter']);
} //it says it is a string


let routeParam = null;

this.router.navigate(['/heroes', {parameter: routeParam}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Better way to handle this compare `null` to the value:

```
queryparams.key === null
```

and other reference check this link

https://angular.io/api/router/Params

Comment: According that page, it could return any type of objects, so it should be able to return a null object as well (and not a string like in my example), I guess.